# How do I access JSON array data?

Tags: ruby, arrays, json

I have the following array:

```
[ { "attributes": {
      "id":   "usdeur",
      "code": 4
    },
    "name": "USD/EUR"
  },
  { "attributes": {
      "id":   "eurgbp",
      "code": 5
    },
    "name": "EUR/GBP"
  }
]
```

How can I get both ids for futher processing as output?

I tried a lot but no success. My problem is I always get only one id as output:

```
Market.all.select.each do |market|
  present market.id
end
```

Or:

```
Market.all.each{|attributes| present attributes[:id]}
```

which gives me only "eurgbp" as a result while I need both ids.

Comment: That looks like a JSON array, not a Ruby array...

Comment: @Jordan - correct. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Unless you convert your keys to symbols, JSON structures are strings and strings only for keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON#parse` should help you with this

```
require 'json'

json = '[ { "attributes": {
             "id":   "usdeur",
             "code": 4
           },
            "name": "USD/EUR"
           },
         { "attributes": {
            "id":   "eurgbp",
            "code": 5
           },
           "name": "EUR/GBP"
         }]'

ids = JSON.parse(json).map{|hash| hash['attributes']['id'] }
#=> ["usdeur", "eurgbp"]
```

`JSON#parse` turns a jSON response into a `Hash` then just use standard `Hash` methods for access.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that the data is JSON that you're parsing (with `JSON.parse`) into a Ruby Array of Hashes, which would look like this:

```
hashes = [ { "attributes" => { "id" => "usdeur", "code" => 4 },
             "name"       => "USD/EUR"
           },
           { "attributes" => { "id" => "eurgbp", "code" => 5 },
             "name"       => "EUR/GBP"
           } ]
```

If you wanted to get just the first `"id"` value, you'd do this:

```
first_hash = hashes[0]
first_hash_attributes = first_hash["attributes"]
p first_hash_attributes["id"]
# => "usdeur"
```

Or just:

```
p hashes[0]["attributes"]["id"]
# => "usdeur"
```

To get them all, you'll do this:

```
all_attributes = hashes.map {|hash| hash["attributes"] }
# => [ { "id" => "usdeur", "code" => 4 },
#      { "id" => "eurgbp", "code" => 5 } ]

all_ids = all_attributes.map {|attrs| attrs["id"] }
# => [ "usdeur", "eurgbp" ]
```

Or just:

```
p hashes.map {|hash| hash["attributes"]["id"] }
# => [ "usdeur", "eurgbp" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON library what using Rails is very slowly...

I prefer to use:

```
gem 'oj'
```

from https://github.com/ohler55/oj

fast and simple! LET'S GO!